# java how to implement my object class with char array to a main class

Tags: java, arrays, encapsulation

This code is a class of char array. I do probably have any mistake with data encapsulation. And how can I test this Object class in a Main class?

```
public class CharList {
    private char[] characters;

    public char[] getCharacters() {
        return characters;
    }

    public void setCharacters(char[] characters) {
        this.characters = characters;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is impossible to give you design advices without knowing exactly how you intend to use this class. Generally speaking you might want to drop the setter and favor immutable classes and the getter should maybe return a copy or unmodifable wrapper view of the array. Also, the field should likely be set through a constructor. All in all, if that is all this class will offer, I would question its existance, it is not better than a raw `char[]`, user might as well just use that instead...

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking, but if you're asking how to test it you could use a unit test framework like JUnit or TestNG and write a test for it?

Comment: - i have to Rewrite the two methods given so that the law of data encapsulation is no longer violated. 
- Also add a public standard constructor, also in compliance with the law of data encapsulation.
- Testing the methods you have just changed and the standard constructor in a main program.

Answer (score 0):

(A) Sounds like you have not mastered the essential basics of Java. Stack Overflow is not the place for that. See the free-of-cost Java Tutorials by Oracle.

(B) The `char` type is obsolete, unable to represent even half of the characters defined by Unicode and supported by Java.

(C) Your code is basically recreating the `String` or `StringBuilder` classes, with no value added. I hope this is merely an exercise, not real work.

(D) Your code is not necessarily breaking encapsulation. The goal of encapsulation is to not divulge internal implementation details. So we don’t want to advertise that internally we use an array of `char`. But we still need to communicate data inputs and outputs. The fact that you communicate data as a `char` array could be considered a coincidence. In the earliest days of Java, an array of `char` would sometimes be used, but not today.

Communicating inputs and outputs as `CharSequence` objects makes more sense nowadays. Your constructor/setter could accept a `CharSequence` Object (such as a `String` object), and loop through the characters to create the `char` array.

And as mentioned above, the `char` type is obsolete. If you really want to focus on each character, you should be using an array of `int` integer numbers, each number representing the Unicode code point number assigned to that character by the Unicode Consortium.

Java offers classes with many methods for working with code point numbers as the successor to the `char` type.

Example class:

```java
package work.basil.demo;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

// A solution for Question on Stack Overflow:
// https://stackoverflow.com/q/67642713/642706
// Note: This class is *not* thread-safe.
// Note: This class has *not* been tested.
public class Characters
{
    private int[] codePoints;

    // Constructors

    public Characters ( CharSequence charSequence )
    {
        this.set( Objects.requireNonNull( charSequence ) );
    }

    public Characters ( char[] arrayOfChar )
    {
        // Be aware that `char` type is obsolete in modern Java.
        this.set( Objects.requireNonNull( arrayOfChar ) );
    }

    public Characters ( )
    {
        this.set( "" );  // Default to empty string, for an empty array.
    }

    // Accessors

    public void set ( CharSequence charSequence )
    {
        this.codePoints = Objects.requireNonNull( charSequence ).codePoints().toArray();
    }

    public void set ( char[] chars )
    {
        this.set( String.valueOf( Objects.requireNonNull( chars ) ) );
    }

    public IntStream codePointsAsStream ( )
    {
        return IntStream.of( this.codePoints );
    }

    public List < Integer > codePointsAsList ( )
    {
        return IntStream.of( this.codePoints ).boxed().collect( Collectors.toList() );  // In Java 16+, use `.toList()` in place of `.collect( Collectors.toList() )`.
    }

    public CharSequence asCharSequence ( )
    {
        return new String( this.codePoints , 0 , this.codePoints.length );
    }

    // `Object` methods

    @Override
    public boolean equals ( final Object o )
    {
        if ( this == o ) return true;
        if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) return false;
        final Characters that = ( Characters ) o;
        return Arrays.equals( codePoints , that.codePoints );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ( )
    {
        return Arrays.hashCode( codePoints );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "Characters{ " +
                "codePoints=" + Arrays.toString( codePoints ) +
                " }";
    }
}
```

Demo usage.

```java
Characters characters = new Characters();
System.out.println( "characters = " + characters );

characters.set( "test after empty" );
System.out.println( "characters = " + characters );
System.out.println( "characters as CharSequence = " + characters.asCharSequence() );

characters = new Characters( "dog" );
System.out.println( characters.asCharSequence() + " = " + characters.codePointsAsStream() );
characters.set( "abc" );
System.out.println( characters.asCharSequence() + " = " + characters.codePointsAsList() );

characters = new Characters( "" );
System.out.println( "characters with FACE WITH MEDICAL MASK character as CharSequence = " + characters.asCharSequence() );

// Caution: The `char` type is obsolete in modern Java. Unfortunately, it is still in use.
char[] arrayOfChar = { 'x' , 'y' , 'z' };
characters = new Characters( arrayOfChar );
System.out.println( "characters from array of char as CharSequence = " + characters.asCharSequence() );
```

Results.

```
characters = Characters{ codePoints=[] }
characters = Characters{ codePoints=[116, 101, 115, 116, 32, 97, 102, 116, 101, 114, 32, 101, 109, 112, 116, 121] }
characters as CharSequence = test after empty
dog = java.util.stream.IntPipeline$Head@19469ea2
abc = [97, 98, 99]
characters with FACE WITH MEDICAL MASK character as CharSequence = 
characters from array of char as CharSequence = xyz
```